# wsl2 mounting nfs mount.nfs: No such device

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nfs

When trying to mount a NFS server in WSL2 on Windows 10 (Linux version 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com)), Ubuntu 20.04, I get:

mount.nfs: No such device

The server being specified is reachable and other Linux clients are able to mount that same path.
There does not seem to be a tutorial I can find to see if I am missing some steps.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you specified the kernel information!  That kernel says that your instance is WSL1, not WSL2.

`uname -a`

*WSL1*: `Linux Revel 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #488-Microsoft Mon Sep 01 13:43:00 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

*WSL2*: `Linux Revel 4.19.104-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Wed Feb 19 06:37:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

My guess is that you may have installed WSL2, but didn't convert your existing WSL1 instance to WSL2.  Converting your instance to WSL2 should fix the issue.

Assuming that you do actually have [WSL2 installed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), then you can do this through either ...

- `wsl --set-version <Distro> 2`
- Or, clone the WSL1 instance with `wsl --export <distroName> <filename.tgz>` and then import that back in as WSL2 with `wsl --import <newDistroName> <DirectoryWhereYouWantIt> <filenameYouCreatedFromExport.tgz> --version 2`.  More details in the first part of my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067679/11810933).
- Or a "middle ground" approach between the two.  Back up the existing instance with `wsl --export`, test it with a `wsl --import`, convert the original with `wsl --set-version`, and then delete the one you don't need with `wsl --unregister`.

Comment: Thanks. That probably was it and 'wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2' woked fine. However, now starting wsl returns 'The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced', so something did not go well. I will try reboot but any suggestions to trouble-shoot this would be appreciated!

Comment: Ugh, from a quick Google search, that looks like it could be a more substantial issue.  Do you have a VPN in Windows?  If so, see [this thread/comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5351#issuecomment-645298068).  If not, try [this one](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/547), but that requires re-installing.

Comment: Looks like a lot of other users are complaining about the same issue. Am switching back to V1 as the couple of options I tried did not resolve the issue. Some combination of https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5351 & https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4177#issuecomment-597736482 point to the issue. Luckily switching back seemed to be work - will try the clone process next time :-)

Comment: we just swapped messages - yes on the same page. I do have a corporate VPN. Will try these when I some play time! Thanks!